# PHP HTML Mail message going to spam

Tags: php, email

When my client tries this out, the messages are always going to spam. Before I tell him it's just his settings, I wanted to be sure there isn't anything in here that would be making it go to spam. Anything in the HTML message stand out to you as an issue?

```
$to        = $_POST["email"];
$promo      = $_POST["promo"];
$subject    = 'Laser Wash - Wash Code';
$message    = '<style>
                    body {
                        padding: 10px !important;
                        margin: 0 0 0 0 !important;
                        text-align: center !important;
                        color: #fff !important;
                        font-family: Arial;
                    }
                    table, tr, td {
                        padding: 0 0 0 0 !important;
                        margin: 0 0 0 0 !important;
                        color: #fff !important;
                        font-family: Arial;
                    }
                    table {
                        background: #000 url(http://www.noahyamen.com/laser/img/background.jpg) no-repeat;
                        text-align: center !important;
                        margin: 0 auto 0 auto !important;
                        width: 550px !important;
                        height: 590px !important;
                        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
                        -moz-box-shadow:    0px 10px 20px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
                        box-shadow:         0px 10px 20px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
                    }
                </style>
                <body style="padding: 10px !important; margin: 0 0 0 0 !important; text-align: center !important; color: #fff !important; font-family: Arial;">
                    <table style="background: #000 url(http://www.noahyamen.com/laser/img/background.jpg) no-repeat; text-align: center !important; margin: 0 auto 0 auto !important; width: 550px !important; height: 590px !important; -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5); -moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5); box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding: 35px !important; height: 87px !important;"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.noahyamen.com/laser/img/executive-laser-wash-logo.gif" width="247" height="87" alt="Executive Laser Car Wash" /></a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding: 20px !important; font-size: 18px !important; height: 18px !important;">Your wash code is below:</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding: 25px !important; font-family: Impact; font-size: 40px !important; height: 40px !important; background: url(http://www.noahyamen.com/laser/img/promo-code-background.gif) no-repeat center; text-transform: uppercase !important;">'.$promo.'</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>    
                </body>';
$headers    =   'From: info@executivelaserwash.com' . "\r\n" .
                'Reply-To: info@executivelaserwash.com' . "\r\n" .
                'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" .
                'Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1' . "\r\n" .
                'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

Comment: To avoid having your emails placed in spam folders you need to build reputation for your sending domain. Products like mailgun help facilitate this.

Comment: There are countless reasons. External images, MX Record, SPF Record, HTML mail without plaintext alternative, ...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about diagnosing email deliverability problems, not about programming.

Comment: Every email server has a different collection of antispam rules.  There is not one single way to make sure that you aren't seen as spam. Besides, if there was, then all the spammers would do that, and then the rule would change.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes people subscribe to services that filter base don black lists and a mail server's IP Address or hostname can be added to these lists (i.e. spambot) and that becomes out of your control. You'd have to engage the filter list creator directly and it's usually a pain since you have to be notified your mail was filtered by someone.

It can depend on the end user's spam filter too so it's always tricky to see why its being marked as spam because even default filters contain some arbitrary red flags like certain phrases in from addresses or subject lines that appear "suspect".

Answer (score 0):

I believe it can help to include the display names for the recipient (and possibly the sender too but I am not sure about this).

Something like

`$to = 'Executive Laser Wash <info@executivelaserwash.com>';`

might help.